# Preload de Fotos

Tags: php, javascript

Como faço um preload com loading ou uma gif em minhas fotos.

```
<?php

$diretorio = '../fotos/';
$arquivos = scandir($diretorio);

foreach($arquivos as $arquivo) {
  if(preg_match("/.+.[jJ][pP][eE]?[gG]$/", $arquivo)) {
    ?>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
    <a href="fotos/<?php echo $arquivo; ?>" class="portfolio-box" data-gallery="Galeria_Cachoeira" data-toggle="lightbox">
        <img src="fotos/<?php echo $arquivo; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="">
        <div class="portfolio-box-caption">
            <div class="portfolio-box-caption-content">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fullscreen"></span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
<?php
  }
}
exit;
?>
```

Comment: https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Image-Preloader-With-Callback-jQuery/ da uma olhada se ajuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vc pode fazer por css

```
.loading {
  background: transparent url('http://thinkfuture.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/loading_spinner.gif') center no-repeat;
}

<img class="loading" src="http://placehold.it/106&text=1" width="106px" height="106px" />
<img class="loading" src="http://placehold.it/106&text=2" width="106px" height="106px" />
<img class="loading" src="http://placehold.it/106&text=3" width="106px" height="106px" />
<img class="loading" src="http://placehold.it/106&text=4" width="106px" height="106px" />
<img class="loading" src="http://placehold.it/106&text=5" width="106px" height="106px" />
<img class="loading" src="http://placehold.it/106&text=6" width="106px" height="106px" />
<img class="loading" src="http://placehold.it/106&text=7" width="106px" height="106px" />
```

```css
.loading {
  background: transparent url('http://thinkfuture.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/loading_spinner.gif') center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<img class="loading" src="http://placehold.it/106&text=1" width="106px" height="106px" />
<img class="loading" src="http://placehold.it/106&text=2" width="106px" height="106px" />
<img class="loading" src="http://placehold.it/106&text=3" width="106px" height="106px" />
<img class="loading" src="http://placehold.it/106&text=4" width="106px" height="106px" />
<img class="loading" src="http://placehold.it/106&text=5" width="106px" height="106px" />
<img class="loading" src="http://placehold.it/106&text=6" width="106px" height="106px" />
<img class="loading" src="http://placehold.it/106&text=7" width="106px" height="106px" />
```

Comment: vc pode testar com imagens mais pesadas ^^

Comment: Vamos aos testes. Obrigado

Comment: eu uso esse ex nos meus sites he simples mas funciona ^^

Comment: O único problema é que com isso a imagem mais pesada vai carregando por cima do gif do loader né, fica um efeito meio estranho... Pois a imagem vai carregando de cima para baixo até cobrir o gif todo...

Comment: geralmente eu trato as imagens com php antes d exibir :(